# Iphone lost photos and videos when jailbreak

Tags: ios, backup, iphone, jailbreak

I need your urgent help. When I opened the photos app and I saw all of my albumns are gone but all the videos and photos are still in my phone. The problem started to happens when I use the jailbreak software called redsn0w as I'm trying to install cydia on my iphone to get the iblacklist software, but it didn't do anything so I decided to stop running the software so that is how it have happens that my abulmns are gone.

I have backed up on my computer and on icloud, but I want to get the albums back that I have created important photos and videos to show to the urology when I see him on Monday.

Any advice will be much appreciate.

Comment: Do a reset in iTunes using your backup, and everything will be fine

Comment: what do you mean by do a reset in iTunes using my backup? how i can restore the albums that i have created with photos?

Comment: As @user2277872 says, simply restore from the back up you made in itunes before you jailbroke your phone and it will go back to how it was before with all your albums in tack. If you didn't back up before you jailbroke your phone quit frankly you don't deserve to get back what you lost and you should be grateful you didn't lose more.

Comment: iBlacklist is amazing. I used to use it. It's been kept up to date and it should work just fine. One thing you have to do is reboot your iPhone after you install iBlacklist otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson how did you install iblacklist on your iphone? can you please help me with it as I have got all of my pictures, videos and albums back as I used the software called `iFunbox`, it act like a computer hard drive where it can find the pictures, videos and albums from RAW so I have moved them back to where it was and I got them back. I want to take more careful this time as I want to backup all of my contacts, sms messages, notes, reminders, videos, pictures, app and everything that goes on my computer. I hope you will help me with this.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson did you install iBlackList when you installed cydia on your iphone? if not please let me know and how you did it. I want to install iBlackList on my iphone to stop the private companies sending me harassment messages.

Comment: Once you're jailbroken, open up Cydia, click the Search tab, and search for iBlacklist, click iBlacklist, and then click Install in the top right corner. Reboot your phone after it installs and resprings.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Thank you, but I have a problem with jailbreak on my iphone as something has stop working. I guess that I have missed something. Did you downloaded the firewire file with type called .ipsw to allow the jailbreak to process? you did not recommend me what software I should use to backup my iphone? is it possible to install cydia on my iphone without jailbreak?

Comment: To jailbreak your iPhone, you'll need to go to http://canijailbreak.com and learn how to do it based on the iOS version you have. For all intents and purposes, an IPSW file cannot jailbreak your phone. Cydia requires you to be jailbroken and comes pre-installed with the jailbreak.

Comment: Yes I can jailbreak my phone using redsn0w. Have you used them before? I don't know how to jailbreak my iphone as i have tried it few times and I did not get successful :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37780/discussion-between-andrew-larsson-and-user3788310).

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is restore your iPhone from the latest backup you made. In order to do that, follow these steps:

[image]

As you can see, this is from apple's website, so those are the directions.

If you did not create a backup before jail breaking, it is going to take a more complicated route to find your photos and videos, if it's even possible at that point.

Hope this helps!